# What is never equal to itself?

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

Is there value in Prolog that is not equal to itself? I write [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53404595/10631003) to some [question about min of tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53399006/10631003) and this answer also says that if tree is empty min is null. Sounds good idea first but now when I think it sounds like bad idea.

It is kinda OK if `null <> null`, no problem. But in Prolog I see null is just atom so....

```
?- null = null.
true.

?- null == null.
true.

?- dif(null, null).
false.
```

How can I make some term in Prolog that always say:

```
?- dif(Something, Something).
true.
```

But if it is any other thing and not this term that is the `null` thing still say `false.`?

Or if this is not how I should think in Prolog then how should I think about not `true.` and also not `false.` but "neither true nor false because something is missing"?

Comment: Such a thing is not possible, you'd have to make your own predicate with the semantics you want, probably by pattern matching on an atom like null.

Comment: @DanielLyons but how do you know it is not possible? If it is possible but you do not know is it the same as not possible? Because in Prolog if it is not true it is false but in reality if it is not true maybe it is also not false but we just do not know it. Like null.

Comment: Prolog's `=` operator is not simply a way of asking if two things are equal, it is the heart and soul of unification itself which is one of the two major differences between Prolog and all other languages. It would be quite a strange and warty mess if that operator sometimes did not unify simply because some imperative programmer came along wanting to repeat [the billion dollar mistake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare#Apologies_and_retractions). Again, you could make your own equality predicate, but as you suspect, null is just a bad idea that has no place in declarative programming.

Comment: As far as the answer you gave to the other question, it is up to you whether you want a list that really has no minimum to actually succeed with a minimum of `null`. As your code in that answer shows, it does become a little cumbersome dealing with the `null` case. It's easier to just define the predicate such that it succeeds if there is a minimum, but fails otherwise. Which is better? It depends upon the use case, which often isn't given in such questions.

Comment: *Because in Prolog if it is not true it is false but in reality if it is not true maybe it is also not false but we just do not know it.* Yes, but false means "not provable". Prolog can only tell you if it can prove something. If it can't, it fails. It has no way of knowing the "universe of what is possible but not provable" with the given facts/rules. So it can't have a "maybe" answer. `null` itself, as you say, is just an atom. It has no truth value. `null \= null` must be false since `null` is an atom and, in Prolog, if two atoms are identical, they are necessarily (trivially) unifiable.

Comment: @lurker I understand maybe that `null` is atom. What I try to ask in so bad and difficult to understand words is how to cleanly model "lack of information about value" in Prolog.

Comment: @DanielLyons You seem so certain and explain so forcefully easy things but I am not certain that you understand what my question asks. I certainly write bad question because it is difficult for people to understand concept. I am sorry for silly question :-(

Comment: The literal answer to your literal question is that you cannot. Paulo has seen past your wording to your intent and given you an interesting answer, but it is still more complex than changing unification (and it is specific to a particular dialect of Prolog). Still, I don't think it is silly to ask questions like this. It indicates confusion, but confusion is the heart of learning. You cannot learn if you are not confused. But there is no place for shame in learning, so if I have offended you I apologize.

Comment: I think I did explain in my comment about handling *lack of information about value*. As I mentioned, Prolog's response of false doesn't really mean that the query can't be true if given adequate information. Rather, it means it cannot be proven with the information (facts and rules) that are known. I don't see how it can infer for unless you express rules about the missing information. But then, of course, you've then provided some of the information that is missing. :)

Comment: I suspect, though, that I'm probably not fully understanding your thought.

Comment: @lurker I suspect I am not fully understanding my thought. I will edit question to help understanding when I have time to think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for fun, not really the answer you're looking for, taking the question title quite literally:

```
?- _ == _ .
false.
```

But `dif/2` is not fouled (hint: each occurrence of the *anonymous variable* represents a different variable):

```
?- dif(_, _).
true.
```

Now, seriously. Starting with your tree minimum predicate example, there's a trivial alternative: the predicate can simply fail when the tree is empty. A better alternative may be to use *optional* or *expected* term libraries. The concepts behind these libraries are found in several programming languages, where they provide a better alternative to *null*. You have both libraries in Logtalk, which you can use with most Prolog systems. See:

- https://logtalk.org/library/optional_0.html
- https://logtalk.org/library/optional_1.html

and

- https://logtalk.org/library/expected_0.html
- https://logtalk.org/library/expected_1.html

You use one library or the other depending on your interpretation of "missing" meaning something that is *optional* (absence of a value is fine) or *expected* (absence of a value is an error). For example, assume that in your particular application it makes sense to use `0` as the minimum value of an empty tree when doing a **specific** computation (e.g. the sum of the minimums of a set of trees). If the tree minimum predicate returns an optional term reference, `Ref`, instead of an integer, you could do e.g.

```
...,
optional(Ref)::or_else(Minimum, 0),
Sum1 is Sum0 + Minimum,
...
```

This is a cleaner solution compared with using an if-then-else construct:

```
...,
(   tree_minimum(Tree, Minimum) ->
    Sum1 is Sum0 + Minimum
;   Sum1 is Sum0
),
...
```

It also allows you to use different defaults for different computations. For example:

```
...,
optional(Ref)::or_else(Minimum, 1),
Product1 is Product0 * Minimum,
...
```

More important, it doesn't mask that you're processing an empty tree in the same way that a default value would do. For example, the following code will only write the minimum values of non-empty trees:

```
print_tree_minimums(Refs) :-
    meta::map(print_tree_minimum, Refs).

print_tree_minimum(Ref) :-
    optional(Ref)::if_present(write).
```

or, using a lambda expression:

```
print_tree_minimums(Refs) :-
    meta::map([Ref]>>(optional(Ref)::if_present(write)), Refs).
```

This answer is getting long and I don't want to transform it into a general discussion of the pros and cons of *optionals* and *expecteds*. But descriptions on both concepts and libraries is easy to find. E.g.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type

https://youtu.be/NhcHwkUPX7w

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you so much Paulo Moura! So this is somehow similar to optional in Java if I read correctly? It still does not solve problem but better than "ooh you cannot".

Comment: Thanks. Java optionals indeed provide similar functionality.

Comment: I cannot yet accept answer because I now understand that no one really understood question of mine which was not very good. Still you give excellent answer and I will try to make better question and try your approach you explain in this answer.

Comment: @MunDong it would be better in such a circumstance to accept Paulo's answer and then ask a new question, if it would be different enough to require a different answer.

Comment: @DanielLyons Thank you very much for your kind suggestion. But if the asnwer does not answer the question or if I do not yet know certainly if it answers the question because I have not yet tried out the code on my own than you can kindly wait until I know for certain, then I can accept the answer.